# How to convert my date and time variables into Unix timestamp? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp

My project schedules a message to be sent at a specific day and time, I store the day in one variable and the time in another. How can I convert these two variables to a unix timestamp?

var date = "2023-03-14"; //example date(i get this from a weekDays-selector)

var time = "09:10:00"; //example time

Comment: ``new Date(`${date}T${time}`).getTime() / 1000`` converts this to a Unix timestamp in your local time zone.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to parse a date of the form `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss`.

So you could try this:

```js
const date = "2023-03-14";
const time = "09:10:00";
const timestamp = Date.parse(`${date}T${time}`);
console.log(timestamp);
```

Comment: For reference, `Date.parse('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00');` should be `0` since the timestamp is ms since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    const date = '2023-03-14'
    const [year, month, day] = date.split('-')
    const time = '09:10:00'
    const [hour, minutes, seconds] = time.split(':')
    
    const myDate = new Date(year, month-1, day, hour, minutes, seconds)
    console.log(myDate)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

Comment: Hello, why does the month need the -1 in new Date()?

Comment: the Date constructor accepts a monthIndex parameter integer value representing the month beginning with 0 for January and 11 for December